# Thunderbird 17.0 message filters destroying my emails

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird

I have been using Thunderbird for years in the following manner (now it's Thunderbird 17.0 on Windows 7):

*I offload my IMAP emails to my local inbox weekly, then apply hundreds of message filters to said emails in order to move and store them into a few hundred subfolders. It's always worked like a charm - until recently.*

Now, after I apply the message filters, the emails get moved but they are destroyed in the process - bodies are scrambled up, with bits and pieces of **other** emails or they are simply blank!

How do I fix this?

Comment: I suggest that first try reinstalling TB 17.0 -- what you describe sounds very uncommon so perhaps something is corrupted.

Comment: A) "until recently" can be pretty anything.  Can you be more specific (I know it can be hard, but often a guess is better than nothing). B) could you more specifically describe how the messages are garbled? (real sample would be best, if policies allow it)

Comment: Maybe the simplest option: Too large mail folders ... broken index database in some of them? Make a copy of your profile folder as a backup and then try rebuilding the index files for each folder ...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I know how to make a profile back-up using MozBackup but how do I "rebuild the index files for each folder"?

Comment: The emails become garbled with a lot of code, like this: </div>
                          <div style=3D"color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:
                            'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; font-size: 12px;
                            "><br>
                          </div>
                          <div style=3D"color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:
                            'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; font-size: 12px;
                            ">
                            <div style=3D"font-family: Calibri; font-size:

Comment: and it's clear that the various code snippets are themselves from other emails, not even the same email. So yes, maybe something is corrupted and I have to re-install...

Comment: Okay so I backed up then uninstalled and re-installed Thunderbird. The problem persists. I did notice though that if I apply the message filters to a single email, it moves it without problem. If there is more than 1 email in the box, then all emails get scrambled once moved.

Comment: Checking Mozilla support and looks like it's a known bug. They are working on it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=815012